# Java Abstract, Generics, and Builders

Tags: java, generics

this is my first time posting but I'm having a lot of trouble with a problem.
I currently have an AbstractDevice class with the header:

```
public abstract class AbstractDevice<T extends AbstractDevice.Builder<T>> implements Device
```

and this class has a nested builder class with the header:

```
public static abstract class Builder<T>
```

I also have a AbstractPeripheral class with the header:

```
public abstract class  AbstractPeripheral<T extends AbstractPeripheral.Builder<T>> extends AbstractDevice<AbstractPeripheral.Builder>
```

and this class also has its own nested builder class with the header:

```
public static abstract class Builder<T> extends AbstractDevice.Builder<Builder>.
```

My goal is the have the AbstractPeripheral extend the AbstractDevice and the AbstractPeripheral's builder extend AbstractDevice's. However, I am getting this error when trying to compile:

> type argument uxb.AbstractPeripheral.Builder is not within bounds of type-variable T.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks
Abstract Device:

```
package uxb;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public abstract class AbstractDevice<T extends AbstractDevice.Builder<T>>     
implements Device{

public static abstract class Builder<T>{

private Integer version;

private Optional<Integer> productCode;

private Optional<BigInteger> serialNumber;

private List<Connector.Type> connectors;

public Builder(Integer version){
  this.version = version;
}  //end constructor method


public T productCode(Integer productCode){
  if(productCode != null){
    this.productCode = Optional.of(productCode); 
  }  //end if statement
  else{
    this.productCode = Optional.empty();
  }  //end else statement
  return getThis();
}  //end method productCode()

public T serialNumber(BigInteger serialNumber){
  if(serialNumber != null){
    this.serialNumber = Optional.of(serialNumber);
  }  //end if statement
  else{
  /*Class has a static field for ZERO value*/
    this.serialNumber = Optional.empty();
  }  //end else statement
  return getThis();
}  //end method serialNumber()


public T connectors(List<Connector.Type> connectors){
 this.connectors = connectors;
 return getThis();
}  //end method connectors


protected abstract T getThis();


protected List<Connector.Type> getConnectors(){
  return connectors;
}  //end method getConnectors()


protected void validate(){
  if(version == null){
    throw new NullPointerException("Cannot be validated");
  }
}  //end method validate()

}  //end nested abstract class Builder


private final Integer version;

private final Optional<Integer> productCode;


private final Optional<BigInteger> serialNumber;

private final List<Connector.Type> connectors;

private final List<Connector> connectorObjects;


protected AbstractDevice(Builder<T> builder){
  this.version = builder.version;
  this.productCode = builder.productCode;
  this.serialNumber = builder.serialNumber;
  this.connectors = builder.connectors;
  ArrayList<Connector> temp = new ArrayList<Connector>();
  for(int i = 0; i < connectors.size(); i++){
    temp.add(new Connector(this, i, connectors.get(i)));
  }  //end for loop
  connectorObjects = temp;
}  //end constructor method



public Optional<Integer> getProductCode(){
return productCode;
}  //end method getProductCode()


public Integer getConnectorCount(){
/*Not Implemented Yet*/
return 0;
}  //end method getConnectorCount()



public Optional<BigInteger> getSerialNumber(){
return serialNumber;
}  //end method getSerialNumber()


public Integer getVersion(){
return version;
}  //end method getVersion()

public List<Connector> getConnectors(){
return new ArrayList<Connector>(connectorObjects);
}  //end method getConnectors()


public Connector getConnector(int index){
  if(! getConnectors().isEmpty()){
  return getConnectors().get(index);
}  //end if statement
else{
  return null;
}  //end else statement
}  //end method getConnector()

} //end abstract class AbstractDevice
```

Abstract Peripheral:
    package uxb;

```
import java.util.List;

public abstract class  AbstractPeripheral<T extends  
AbstractPeripheral.Builder<T>> extends 
AbstractDevice<AbstractPeripheral.Builder>{

public static abstract class Builder<T> extends 
AbstractDevice.Builder<Builder>{

protected void validate(){
  super.validate();
  if(getConnectors().equals(null)){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot be validated");
  }  //end if statement
  if(checkTypes(getConnectors())){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot be validated");
  }  //end if statement
}  //end method 

private boolean checkTypes(List<Connector.Type> types){
  for(Connector.Type type: types){
    if(type != Connector.Type.PERIPHERAL){
      return false;
    }  //end if statement
  }  //end for each loop
  return true;
}  //end method checkTypes

public Builder(Integer version){
  super(version);
}  //end constructor method
}  //end nested class Builder

public AbstractPeripheral(Builder<T> builder){
 super(builder);
} 
}  //end class AbstractPeripheral
```

Hub:
    package uxb;

```
public class Hub extends AbstractDevice<Hub.Builder>{

  public static class Builder extends AbstractDevice.Builder<Builder>{

public Builder(Integer version){
  super(version);
} //end constructor method

public Hub build(){
 validate();
 return new Hub(getThis());
}  //end method build()

protected Builder getThis(){
  return this;
} //end method getThis()

protected void validate(){
  super.validate();
  if(!(super.getConnectors().contains(Connector.Type.COMPUTER))){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot be validated");
  }  //end if statement\
  if(!(super.getConnectors().contains(Connector.Type.PERIPHERAL))){
    throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot be validated");
  }  //end if statement
}  //end validate()
}  //end nested class Builder

private Hub(Builder builder){
super(builder);
}  //end constructor method

public DeviceClass getDeviceClass(){
return DeviceClass.HUB;
}  //end method getDeviceClass()


}  //end class Hub
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code?

Comment: abstract overflow

Comment: What is your intent for `<T extends AbstractDevice.Builder<T>>`

Comment: I think with <T extends AbstractDevice.Builder<T>> the generic of the Abstract device has to extend the AbstractDevice.Builder<T> not 100% sure tho it was given to me in the assignment. Also, how would i go about posting my code?

Comment: I also had to make a non abstract class to extend AbstractDevice and had no problem with that:

Comment: public class Hub extends AbstractDevice<Hub.Builder>

Comment: public static class Builder extends AbstractDevice.Builder<Builder>

Comment: Just [edit] the question

Comment: The class being built shouldn't know anything about the builder class, but your abstract device type takes an abstract device builder as its type. That design is broken.

Comment: Does that mean Im not using the abstract device correctly when implementing hub?

Comment: You should parameterize the `Builder` with both the type it is building, and the builder's own type. I'll try and find some examples and post them in an answer.

Comment: Thanks. examples would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need to use both the class being built, *and* the builder, as parameters on the builder. The object being build does *not* need to know about the builder, however, so does not require it as a parameter.

I have used this pattern or slight variations in several open source projects, including [Apache Brooklyn](https://github.com/apache/brooklyn-server/blob/2edf7168d6204c4b724eea95e2f6999232303f52/core/src/main/java/org/apache/brooklyn/core/config/BasicConfigKey.java#L91) and jclouds.

So, from your example, change the parent class as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractDevice implements Device {
    public static abstract class Builder<T, B> {
        public abstract B self();
        public abstract T build();
        public B example(String value) {
            // do something with value
            return self();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added an abstract `build()` method as well, which will return the built object. The `self()` method is required because when if builder methods were to return `this` it would have the wrong type. Instead, each builder method must end with `return self();` as in the `example(String value)` method shown. Then the child becomes:

```
public abstract class AbstractPeripheral extends AbstractDevice {
    public static abstract class Builder<T, B> extends AbstractDevice.Builder<T, B> {
    }
}
```

You can see that the `T` and `B` generic parameters are being used to point to the type of the class and the type of the builder respectively. So, to make a concrete class that uses these, something like this should be created:

```
public class Hub extends AbstractPeripheral {
    public static class Builder extends AbstractPeripheral.Builder<Hub, Builder> {
        public static final Builder builder() {
            return new Builder();
        }
        public Builder self() {
            return this;
        }
        public Hub build() {
            return new Hub();
        }
    }
}
```

This also has a static `builder()` method, that returns an instance of the correct `Builder` class, you could also call the constructor directly if you want as well. The `build()` method simply creates and returns the concrete class, and the `self()` method is implemented *here* to return `this` which will have the correct type.

Putting everything together, we can use this to create a `Hub` object as follows:

```
Hub hub = Hub.Builder.builder()
        .example("something")
        .build();
```

Note that the `AbstractDevice.Builder#example(String)` method returns the correct type since it actually calls `Hub#self()`, and `build()` returns a concrete instance of `Hub` as expected.

To take a little of the pain out of this and remove the repeated boilerplate, you could also try using the [Google AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto) project, which we are switching to in jclouds now.

Comment: note that the type parameters *only* need to go on the builder, not on the class being built, i have updated the answer to make this clear